Can we readdress the reputation penalty for downvoting answers?
I believe it is time to readdress the penalty to downvote an answer.  At one point it may have served a purpose but I don't believe that is true anymore.  My motivation comes from search results pointing to SO only to be greeted by a question with multiple answers and half or more are useless.  These answers carry scores of 0 when they should be buried in the background.  From Privileges:

When you vote down, you are nudging that content "down" the page, so
it will be seen by fewer people. Voting down answers is not something
we want you to take lightly, so it is not free.

A good discussion happened here before.  But the logic seems to have passed the network by as it has grown.
With the tremendous amount of users and content available on the Stack Exchange network there are substandard posts being added all the time.  Some are AI generated, some are ignorantly generated, some are just plain wrong.  Using flags places a burden on moderators to act when a simple downvote will move the post out of sight.  The review queues constantly show red now.  This would allow the community to moderate itself.
If a user posts a bad question or answer and the community votes it down, the user can elect to delete it and clean up the site.  Abuses of the voting system are detected and corrected with tools already in place.
An unpopular "happy medium" could be enforce a -1 rep penalty for a downvote on a question or answer unless a comment is added to help the poster.  I know this is unpopular and I would suggest simply eliminating the penalty.

rather closely related -- "answer downvotes should be free unless these are cast on competing answers..."

SO is huge compared to all the other sites on the network, so policies and strategies for SO don't necessarily transfer well to the other sites. This meta is for the whole network. If you're primarily concerned with the mechanics of SO, it's probably better to discuss it on the SO meta.

Any proposal must not involve having to comment upon downvoting, it generates revenge downvotes.

@philipxy I agree which is why my suggestion is to simply eliminate the penalty.

I'd put it another way - I'd like my downvotes to have an effect. I'm taking a potential 1 reputation loss in the expectation that the user ideally will edit their post into shape, which means I get back my 1 rep, the poster I downvoted gets 2 rep back and a 10 rep bonus, and we end up with a better post.
The other possibilities are the post is deleted, either by the community (or moderator) or by the user, in which case, you temporarily 'spent' one reputation you got back to clean up the site.
Finally, you downvoted, and the post is still there. If you did it right, it's lower in the list with the right sort. If you didn't, and other people upvoted it, it's a learning opportunity.
And frankly - if you don't think you want to spend the reputation to downvote, it is fine. Meta moderation tasks are spread throughout the community. Someone else will.

I agree I want the down vote to have an effect since it costs me something to do.  I can up vote complete trash with no penalty.  There's even a badge for using the max votes per day.  I feel like the exchange wants to upvote 4 or 5 mediocre answers instead of down-voting the one completely wrong answer.

@Matt Yeah, I feel ya, especially with the amount of downvote worthy junk around these days. But really, what's more important to you? Some meaningless points, or making a useful contribution to a repository of knowledge?

Someone else will not; someone else does not. For the past month, I have cast hundreds of close votes, downvotes and delete votes on Stack Overflow. The number of posts that this actually led to being closed or deleted in that time is in the low teens. Nobody bothers.

If nobody is willing to cast a vote to close or delete, which have zero cost, why would anyone be willing to cast downvotes?

Well. cause it makes the site better

I want my downvotes to have an effect as well. Turns out, penalising me for the work of curation, and rewarding someone who can earn even one nonconformity/pity/i-get-it upvote with more rep than a consensus of four downvotes with a net gain, does indeed have an effect: it has the effect of making downvotes a waste of time in anything less than a total rejection, because the only people who lose out are the ones casting those downvotes. If my post gets 100 votes, I am guaranteed rep gain when 17% think positively and 83% think negatively of it. What effect does that have? More of the same.

The system already requires 125 reputation to downvote. That's something like 4% of Stack Overflow user accounts, and represents a non-trivial investment in a site and in the Stack Exchange model. My guess is that users aren't really avoiding downvotes on answers because of the reputation penalty. Rather, they just aren't downvoting answers, because they don't see it as a part of their responsibility as a community member in good standing who wants to improve the site.
This is a social, "site culture" problem rather than a technical one.
Aside from that, the much greater problem IMO is inertia. Answers need to get to -1 before delete votes become accessible, and then a consensus needs to emerge from among the far smaller pool of users who may cast answer deletion votes (and there is no explicit system for these users to advertise such votes to each other; they must separately organize if they want to consider such actions, and need to take care to do so in a way that clears the anti-vote-fraud standards). Meanwhile, I have seen terrible, utterly wrong answers with three-digit scores before, when the question was popular enough. In some of these cases I was dismayed to find myself casting the first downvote, many years later.
Not to mention all the duplicate and overlapping answers. Moderators often won't help with these because, as I understood the explanation, it would be unfair to choose one version of the duplicate answer over the other, and deprive one party of all that reputation, when the answers were posted within a few minutes of each other, many years ago. (But on the other hand, it is apparently completely fair that an edit can permanently improve the vote trajectory of an answer on a popular question - or of a question about a common problem - and the editor gets at most 2 rep from this.)
In short: the best work comes from people who don't care about reputation; and for those who do, the problems with the system are far too fundamental for a proposal like "remove the 1 rep penalty for downvoting answers" to move the needle in any discernible way.

With 125 rep (or rep up to thousands) downvoting when appropriate would get you to 1 very quickly. It is not helpful to address the cost of only 1 downvote. I would possibly have 99 rep if I had downvoted every time it was appropriate. If one wants to gain privileges downvoting answers is a great impediment.

I have the issue on the Magento Stack Exchange website, where a lot of answers are of poor quality but I don’t have enough rep to downvote every time, so I just leave the bad content there.


At one point it may have served a purpose but I don't believe that is true anymore

Part of the purpose to prevent users from abusing/overusing the downvote button. I think that you can imagine plenty of ways someone could do that. I don't see why this purpose doesn't still apply.

These answers carry scores of 0 when they should be buried in the background.

There are 2 ways to bury an answer in the background. Either you could downvote the bad answer or upvote the good one (or ideally do both).

Abuses of the voting system are detected and corrected with tools already in place

Those mainly detect things like serial voting, which isn't all the downvote penalty is meant to prevent. Some if is just trigger happy downvoting, or downvoting all answers in Tag X, etc. This is not caught by any tool that I know of.
Here's the other option though:1 reputation isn't all that much. On SO, you have about 2,800 reputation. That's 2,800 downvotes worth. One of your posts getting upvoted is worth 10 downvotes. Downvotes on answers likely don't have a meaningful impact on most peoples reputation. In addition, many answers get fixed up or deleted, so you get your 1 reputation back. And ultimately, if someone doesn't want to downvote answers because of this, there are plenty of other SO users who will.

Your responses all presume a significant volume of reasonable upvoting. This doesn't exist, so those are not realistic dismissals of the proposed change. And there's no reason that tooling can't be built to resolve what remains. We didn't always have serial voting detection, either, that was not a reason to just not have votes at all.

@Nij On much of the network there is a significant volume of reasonable upvoting. And, as well, what I am saying is that if you don't want to downvote bad posts, upvoting only the good ones works too. No votes and you lose 1 rep for an answer downvote are very different things and are uncomparable.

My claim is the down vote button is not being used enough.  -1 trains people to not down vote when they have only 125 rep (ie new users).  For me 1 point is not a big deal.  For new users it's a larger percentage.  My claim is also there are not other SO users who will...because they are not, in my experience.  Upvoting mediocre answers to hide bad ones seems like the wrong solution as well.

"For new users it's a larger percentage" - So, in other words, users with less expereience will tend to be less likely to downvote unless they have very good reason. I don't think thats a bad thing. "Upvoting mediocre answers to hide bad ones seems like the wrong solution as well" - I said upvote good answers, not mediocre answers.

Again, you are stating the ideal response when it does not match the reality situation, regardless of reason. Again, saying we should do something that is proven not to have efficacy and is the current state when reporting the problem will obviously not solve the problem.

@Nij what I am saying that I agree there is currently a problem (at least on some sites). I don't believe removing the downvote penalty is the best solution too said problem. My proposed solution is further encouragement to upvote good answers and downvote bad ones (as ultimately most people shouldn't care about 1 rep that much).

It seems the explixit statement is not enough. Your proposed solutions do not work, because they are the current implementation exactly. The problem exists despite those 'solutions', so they just are not solutions at all, and contribute nothing useful, except to reject the problem at its root.

@Nij There is an infinite number of ways to encourage upvotes on good answers and downvotes on bad ones that haven't been tried, some of which might work.
